# Don't know what "plax" texture is?

Tags: texturing

I have a texture called "Plax" in my textures that I ripped from "God of War (2018)", and I don't know how to use them. Does anyone have a clue? I don't think it's an AO map, because the AO maps in the "God of War (2018)" files commonly use RGB.

[image]

Comment: Hello, it's not clear what you mean, maybe it's a height map, in that case, create a Texture > Image Texture node, open the image, plug it into the Height input of a Vector > Bump Map, and plug this Bump into the Normal input of the Principled BSDF?

Comment: They do look like height-maps. Could you give us a bit more context, to help us along with the guesswork?

Comment: Even better would be to give us a section of the geometry to be textured. Try them as height-maps on a blank plane.